# Getting error in AWS beanstalk : dotenv module not found while running the backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

dotenv module not found.

dotenv is already there in package.json and still it's giving error.

tried to stop and restart but not working

I also tried to run a sample app on elastic branstalk and that worked fine but it only fials with my application.

```
Aug  5 12:39:17 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/index.js:1:1)
Aug  5 12:39:17 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
Aug  5 12:39:17 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
Aug  5 12:39:17 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
Aug  5 12:39:17 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
Aug  5 12:39:17 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
Aug  5 12:39:17 ip-172-31-25-178 web: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Aug  5 12:39:17 ip-172-31-25-178 web: requireStack: [ '/var/app/current/index.js' ]
Aug  5 12:39:17 ip-172-31-25-178 web: }
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: > beezer-web-services@1.0.0 start
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: > node ./index.js
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: throw err;
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: ^
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: Require stack:
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: - /var/app/current/index.js
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/index.js:1:1)
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: requireStack: [ '/var/app/current/index.js' ]
Aug  5 12:39:18 ip-172-31-25-178 web: }
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: > beezer-web-services@1.0.0 start
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: > node ./index.js
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: throw err;
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: ^
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: Require stack:
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: - /var/app/current/index.js
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/index.js:1:1)
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: requireStack: [ '/var/app/current/index.js' ]
Aug  5 12:39:19 ip-172-31-25-178 web: }
```